# .htaccess : Redir only if a var in url. My script My script has a problem

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My .htaccess should work as follows:
It parses the url and checks if an alphanumeric variable whose name I don't know exists in the url.
If so, it redirects to the redirect.php file, otherwise it redirects to the index.php file.
My problem is that if the condition is met, i.e. the url contains a variable, then I'm redirected to... I don't know, I get a 404 error even though my redirect.php file is at the root of my site.

My code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 
RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[0-9a-zA-Z]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?page=$1 [L]
 
 
</IfModule>
```

I searched a lot and I thought my code was good but I can't understand why this redirection to a page that doesn't exist.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? "checks if an alphanumeric variable **whose name I don't know**" - How are you doing this part? Is the "404 error" generated by Apache?

Comment: And... what URL(s) are you actually requesting to test this?

Comment: My htaccess code is complete, no other directive. I use laragon to test sitetest.com and i would like test if the url is like sitetest.com/abc123. If ther is something after .com/ The 404 error is generated by apahe. If there is nothing after .com, the index is shown

Comment: In that case there's nothing "wrong" with the rule you've posted. If you are getting an Apache 404 then it doesn't look like your `.htaccess` file is doing anything. Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled in the server config? Is mod_rewrite installed? (You should remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper.)

Comment: when i use `deny from all`  I have the correct 403 page. So it s enabled. Without 'IfModule' the pb is the same...